# Analogue military time watchface

Tags: apple-watch

Is it possible to get an analogue military time watchface on the Apple iWatch 2?

Like this...
[image]

Comment: Why not use an analog face and use the world clock to show your local time as a complication? It will use the 24 hour time option from the Apple Watch settings if you enable it. If you use a digital face, it will show 24 hour time without needing a world clock complication. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NacuP.png

Comment: If that highly packed screen isn’t implemented, are there specific functions or calculations you desire above others? A partial solution may be all you get.

Comment: Basically all I want is a clock face that goes to 24, not 12.

Answer (score -2):

Not at the moment. You can send feedback to Apple about this: https://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html.